# Optimizing performance of flexible Linq to Entity criteria when retrieving rows from huge database

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have the DB that contains billions of rows.
I created function that recieve from user number of parameters and cut the DB by those parameters. 
This works well for me with small DB(30000 rows), but when I try to use this function on big DB I got `TIMEOUTEXCEPTION from SQLSERVER`.

Here is my code:

```
public static IQueryable<LogViewer.EF.InternetEF.Log> ExecuteInternetGetLogsQuery(FilterCriteria p_Criteria, ref GridView p_Datagrid)
{
    IQueryable<LogViewer.EF.InternetEF.Log> internetQuery = null;

    using (InternetDBConnectionString context = new InternetDBConnectionString())
    {
        internetQuery = context.Logs;
        if ((p_Criteria.DateTo != null && p_Criteria.DateFrom != null))
        {
            internetQuery = internetQuery.Where(c => c.Timestamp >= p_Criteria.DateFrom && c.Timestamp < p_Criteria.DateTo);
        }
        else if (p_Criteria.DateFrom != null && p_Criteria.DateFrom > DateTime.MinValue)
        {
            internetQuery = internetQuery.Where(c => c.Timestamp >= p_Criteria.DateFrom);
        }
        else if (p_Criteria.DateTo != null && p_Criteria.DateTo > DateTime.MinValue)
        {
            internetQuery = internetQuery.Where(c => c.Timestamp < p_Criteria.DateTo);
        }
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(p_Criteria.FreeText))
        {
            internetQuery = internetQuery.Where(c => c.FormattedMessage.Contains(p_Criteria.FreeText));
        }

        if (p_Criteria.Titles.Count > 0)
        {
            internetQuery = internetQuery.AsEnumerable().Where(c => p_Criteria.Titles.Contains(c.Title)).AsQueryable();
        }
        if (p_Criteria.MachineNames.Count > 0)
        {
            internetQuery = internetQuery.AsEnumerable().Where(c => p_Criteria.MachineNames.Contains(c.MachineName)).AsQueryable();
        }
        if (p_Criteria.Severities.Count > 0)
        {
            internetQuery = internetQuery.AsEnumerable().Where(c => p_Criteria.Severities.Contains(c.Severity)).AsQueryable();
        }
        internetQuery= internetQuery.OrderByDescending(c=>c.LogID);
        if (internetQuery.Count() > p_Criteria.TopValue)
        {
            internetQuery = internetQuery.Take(p_Criteria.TopValue);
        }
        p_Datagrid.DataSource = internetQuery;
        p_Datagrid.DataBind();
        return internetQuery;

    }  
}
```

My version of SQL is 2005. 
I got an exception on `p_Datagrid.DataBind();` row.

Any suggetions?
Thanks

Comment: What are the types of the fields? Post your class definitions. Please post the exact error message, not your paraphrasing of it.

Comment: @MarkByers in the second case I got exception that IQueryable doesnot support Contains methods In the first case I got System.NotSupportedException was unhandled by user code Message=Unable to create a constant value of type 'Closure type'. Only primitive types ('such as Int32, String, and Guid') are supported in this context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a week of searching of solution I found this [post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2009/03/26/tip-8-writing-where-in-style-queries-using-linq-to-entities.aspx). This work great with indexed DB with more than billion rows.
Here is my code solution:

```
public static IQueryable<LogViewer.EF.InternetEF.Log> ExecuteInternetGetLogsQuery(FilterCriteria p_Criteria, ref GridView p_Datagrid)
        {

            
            IQueryable<LogViewer.EF.InternetEF.Log> internetQuery = null;
            List<LogViewer.EF.InternetEF.Log> executedList = null;
            using (InternetDBConnectionString context = new InternetDBConnectionString())
            {
                internetQuery = context.Logs;
                if ((p_Criteria.DateTo != null && p_Criteria.DateFrom != null))
                {
                    internetQuery = internetQuery.Where(c => c.Timestamp >= p_Criteria.DateFrom.Value && c.Timestamp < p_Criteria.DateTo.Value);
                }
                else if (p_Criteria.DateFrom != null && p_Criteria.DateFrom > DateTime.MinValue)
                {
                    internetQuery = internetQuery.Where(c => c.Timestamp >= p_Criteria.DateFrom);
                }
                else if (p_Criteria.DateTo != null && p_Criteria.DateTo > DateTime.MinValue)
                {
                    internetQuery = internetQuery.Where(c => c.Timestamp < p_Criteria.DateTo);
                }
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(p_Criteria.FreeText))
                {
                    internetQuery = internetQuery.Where(c => c.FormattedMessage.Contains(p_Criteria.FreeText));
                }

                
                if (p_Criteria.Titles.Count > 0)
                {
                    internetQuery = internetQuery.Where(BuildOrExpression<LogViewer.EF.InternetEF.Log, string>(p => p.Title, p_Criteria.Titles));
                }
                if (p_Criteria.MachineNames.Count > 0)
                {
                    internetQuery = internetQuery.Where(BuildOrExpression<LogViewer.EF.InternetEF.Log, string>(p => p.MachineName, p_Criteria.MachineNames));
                }
                if (p_Criteria.Severities.Count > 0)
                {
                    internetQuery = internetQuery.Where(BuildOrExpression<LogViewer.EF.InternetEF.Log, string>(p => p.Severity, p_Criteria.Severities));
                }


                internetQuery = internetQuery.Take(p_Criteria.TopValue);
                executedList = internetQuery.ToList<LogViewer.EF.InternetEF.Log>();
                executedList = executedList.OrderByDescending(c => c.LogID).ToList<LogViewer.EF.InternetEF.Log>(); ;

                p_Datagrid.DataSource = executedList;

                p_Datagrid.DataBind();


                return internetQuery;

            }
        }



public static Expression<Func<TElement, bool>> BuildOrExpression<TElement, TValue>(
        Expression<Func<TElement, TValue>> valueSelector,
        IEnumerable<TValue> values )
        {
            if (null == valueSelector)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("valueSelector");

            if (null == values)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("values");

            ParameterExpression p = valueSelector.Parameters.Single();

            if (!values.Any())
                return e => false;

            var equals = values.Select(value =>
                (Expression)Expression.Equal(
                     valueSelector.Body,
                     Expression.Constant(
                         value,
                         typeof(TValue)
                     )
                )
            );

            var body = equals.Aggregate<Expression>(
                     (accumulate, equal) => Expression.Or(accumulate, equal)
             );

            return Expression.Lambda<Func<TElement, bool>>(body, p);
        }
```

I hope this will usefull for our community
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

What I can see you have these options:

- Increase the timeout (Bad idé just moves the problem in the future)
- Instead of doing a linq query. Get the data by a store procedure
- Make the grid page. So you just retrieve the data for target page.
- Look at the query plan and see if you can do any indexes on the column that you are doing your `where` statements on and `order by`.
- Why do you need to have billions of rows in a datagrid. What is the requirements? Maybe you can just show `top 1000` or `top 10000`. Because from a user respective I can not see any pros of seeing a grid with a billion rows.

That was just top of my head.

**EDIT**

And if I would have this function I would start looking at this section of the code:

```
if (p_Criteria.Titles.Count > 0)
{
     internetQuery = internetQuery.AsEnumerable().Where(c => p_Criteria.Titles.Contains(c.Title)).AsQueryable();
}
if (p_Criteria.MachineNames.Count > 0)
{
      internetQuery = internetQuery.AsEnumerable().Where(c => p_Criteria.MachineNames.Contains(c.MachineName)).AsQueryable();
}
if (p_Criteria.Severities.Count > 0)
{
      internetQuery = internetQuery.AsEnumerable().Where(c => p_Criteria.Severities.Contains(c.Severity)).AsQueryable();
}
```

This actually make a IEnumerable of the result and then you do the in memory `where` statements with database calls. You might also have a problem doing this because when you call the related tables it call the database. Maybe you can fetch the rows and then do the `contains` with a id of the `IQueryable` . All the pros of having a `IQueryable` diapers when doing this.

Comment: I get top of rows internetQuery.Take(p_Criteria.TopValue);

Answer (score 2):

In general, 'swiss army knife' specification or criteria patterns like this are hard to optimise (i.e. Index at SQL Level), because of the large number of permutations of filter combinations that a client / user can specify. So if you can somehow force the user to specify at least one mandatory criterion, which reduces the rowcount significantly, e.g. by making the Date Range mandatory and no more than one month, I would start there, because then at least we've got something to start when we look at indexing.

Due to the potentially large number of rows, I would assert or validate that the value of `p_Criteria.TopValue` used to limit the rows is always present, and is a sensible number, e.g. `Take(1000)`. You can always warn the user to narrow his / her search range if this threshold is reached.

The major problem is likely to be that filtering on `Titles`, `MachineNames` and `Severities` each calls `AsEnumerable()`, which materializes the query thus far, and thus you evaluate these 3 filters in memory, not in SQL, potentially with large numbers of records. All recent versions of EF are able to convert predicates of the form `Where(c => IEnumerable<X>.Contains(c.Column))` into the SQL `WHERE c.Column IN (X1, X2, X3)`.

i.e. You should remove the `AsEnumerable()` on these 3 filters (and you then don't need to convert back to `AsQueryable()`), i.e.

```
    if (p_Criteria.Titles.Any())
    {
        internetQuery = internetQuery
            .Where(c => p_Criteria.Titles.Contains(c.Title));
    }
    if (p_Criteria.MachineNamesAny())
    {
        internetQuery = internetQuery
            .Where(c => p_Criteria.MachineNames.Contains(c.MachineName));
    }
    if (p_Criteria.Severities.Any())
    {
        internetQuery = internetQuery
            .Where(c => p_Criteria.Severities.Contains(c.Severity));
    }
```

Another issue in the `Take` check, by running `.Count()` in the check, that you are materializing the query (if you haven't already done so). You should instead just run `Take()` directly - no need to check if we've exceeded the rowcount. If there are LESS than `p_Criteria.TopValue` rows then it will return as may rows as are present, i.e. remove the if check and just leave this:

```
internetQuery = internetQuery.Take(p_Criteria.TopValue);
```

Another thing I would look at for performance reasons is whether you can change the FreeText string checks to use `StartsWith` instead of `Contains`. Indexing on SQL database char columns is only effective at the start of the string.
If the `%filter%` wildcard is not needed, then this is obviously different to OP's code, but will use be able to use indexing on the `FreeText` column:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(p_Criteria.FreeText))
{
    internetQuery = internetQuery
        .Where(c => c.FormattedMessage.StartsWith(p_Criteria.FreeText));
}
```

Minor quibble, and won't effect the database performance, but you can reduce the number of branches on your date filtering to just the following:

```
if (p_Criteria.DateFrom != null && p_Criteria.DateFrom > DateTime.MinValue)
{
    internetQuery = internetQuery.Where(c => c.Timestamp >= p_Criteria.DateFrom);
}
if (p_Criteria.DateTo != null && p_Criteria.DateTo > DateTime.MinValue)
{
    internetQuery = internetQuery.Where(c => c.Timestamp < p_Criteria.DateTo);
}
```

From a naming standards point of view, I would also change the name of your Object/DbContext from `*ConnectionString` to `*Context`.

Comment: So how I check Titles, MachineNames and Severities if this is' List<string>' without 'AsEnumerable()'. Because if I remove this step i get Exception that Linq to entity doesnot support 'Contains()'?

Comment: (1) Anyway the user always have to specify at last one criteria to search and have to put TOP number (select top X). So I will never get billion rows. And as I mention before I take top of rows by TAKE().

Answer (score 1):

Since the concrete schema is not available you can try following things.

1. Write a Stored procedure with all your filter criteria and send parameters from code. Then execute the stored procedure from code and check whether you still get time outs. To check how you can call SP's from Entity framework, read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896334.aspx)
2. If you do not succeed with step 1. You might want to review your table design and add Indexes and / or extra filters. To check guidelines on how to index a SQL Server database read [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/59093/Defining-Indexes-with-SQL-Server-2005)
3. You may also want to create a "shadow" copy of your tables to keep archived DB rows. With archived I mean rows which are of no use as of now, but cannot be permanently deleted.

**EDIT :** I agree with @Arion about having a paged grid instead fetching all the rows.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to load all results into your data grid at all. Is it really neccessary? Can you use something like paging to read only first e.g. 100 rows and the rest only on demand?

Answer (score 0):

```
internetQuery = internetQuery.AsEnumerable().Where(c => p_Criteria.Severities.Contains(c.Severity))
```

Is EF smart enough to do queries like this as a join or does it cause a SELECT N + 1 problem?

Otherwise, maybe you're missing an index on something.

I would check the generated SQL first.